# @OrderBy on @OneToMany relationship doesn't work properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using this code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="contraCheque")
@OrderBy("tipo")
private List<ContraChequeRubrica> rubricas;
```

Although hibernate is generating the SQL correctly (`ORDER BY tipo ASC`), the list returned by `getRubricas()` isn't sorted.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The column `tipo` has only two possible values: `'C'` or `'D'`.

I'm expecting results like this:

```
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
```

Rather, i have this:

```
C
C
D
D
C
D
C
```

Comment: If Hibernate does its job, then most probably you are messing up the list somewhere. If you will find the error in your code, please delete the question.

Comment: My code don't even touch this list. It's strange!

Comment: In what order is the list then? Give an example please.

Comment: I've improved my question showing an example.